Wall switch for motorized skylight
I have the following switch in my house that controls a motorized skylight. It’s
Off when it’s in the middle, and the skylight opens when the switch is held up and closes when held down.
I’d like to replace it with a decora style switch similar to the one next to it:


I found this switch by Leviton, but I’m unsure about how to wire it, since they included this diagram:
leviton-5657

Is this the right switch and which terminals I should connect my neutral/red/black wires to?

You do not have neutral on the switch.  You have a white that is hot/switched hot.  The wires should be tested to prove which is always hot, but a guess(which should not be taken as true), is the black is hot, the white and red are the switch hots.

If I understand correctly, you’re suggesting to connect: L1 to white, A1 to black, and B1 to red?

The black(if proven to be always hot) goes to L1.  The white and red to A1/B1.  A1/B1 does not matter except which one opens/closes

You should check to see if this switch has an intermittent throw ( you need to hold it in position like the old one.) Or a positive detent.  ( You move the switch and it stays in that position.)  There could be unwanted consequences with a positive throw switch.

Does this sound right?
The Leviton 56572W is a Decora Plus rocker singlepole AC quiet switch in white color. It has a doublethrow CtrOFF momentary contact. Leviton is a smart choice for today's commercial, residential and industrial buildings. This Leviton 56572W Decora Plus rocker singlepole switch is perfect for commercial use. It has an elegant and functional design and comes in different colors. This switch features an impactresistant thermoplastic body that ensures durability. It is a selfgrounding device, it has a voltage rating of 120/277 VAC and amperage rating of 15 Amp.

@Matthew this site is not a forum ... please do not use comments for providing information ... update the question instead

There appears to be a ground wire in the junction box. Turn the power on and check the three switch wires separately to ground with your multi meter. The wire with 120V +- will be your always hot and should be hooked to the new switch terminal, after turning the power back off, labeled L1. The other two wires on your old switch get hooked up to the load 1 and load 2 terminals. You can check the back of the old switch and there might be some labeling as to the line and load terminals. If the position of the paddle for opening and closing the skylight doesn't agree with you, just swap the two load wires.
